# Python: How to create a function to return specific columns based on input from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to create a function to return two columns based on a value selected from another?

Sample df:

```
one  two   three  year
12   34    561    2001
2    67    781    1999 
34   12    90     2001    
5    67    89     2011
```

desired output

```
one  two  
12   34   
34   12
```

my code so far:

```
def one_two(year):
 return df.loc[df['year'] == year,['one','two']].sort_values(by='one')

#when I input a year:

one_two(2001)

#my output is just the column names

one  two
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. Your function returns a DataFrame of 2 columns and 2 rows.

Comment: The problem is that I wanted the above desired output but my function returns only the two column names without the rows. I didn't even get an error to let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: What is the output of `df['year'].dtype`?

Comment: 'year' is ```dtype: int64```

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Your code works fine. If you work on Jupyter Notebook, try to restart the kernel and reload your data. You can also filter on another column to check if it works.

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook and I have restarted the kernel several times and still getting the same result. For some reason, it works on another column. I don't know how to fix this issue on the year.

Comment: To debug, you can try to convert year column as string. `df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str)` and try `one_two('2001')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code to sort your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[12, 34, 561, 2001],
        [2, 67, 781, 1999],
        [34, 12, 90, 2001],
        [5, 67, 89, 2011]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["one", "two", "three", "year"])

def one_two(year):
 return df.loc[df['year'] == year,['one','two']].sort_values(by='one').reset_index(drop=True)

#when I input a year:

one_two(2001)
```

**Result:**

[image]